# In Google Sheets IF formula over several cells

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this problem wrong, but there's got to be an easy way to do this.

I simply want to see if Certain text is listed above that cell. If it's not, Put that text. If it is put blank.

This is what I have:

```
=if(F4:F5="TEST","","TEST")
```

This gives it an array formula error so I created this:

```
=arrayformula(if(F4:F5="TEST","","TEST"))
```

But I don't need two results... just a yes/no statement. If the cells in this range contain "TEST" leave blank, if it does not contain "TEST" display the word "TEST".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the cells in this range contain "TEST" leave blank, if it does not contain "TEST" display the word "TEST".

Use [COUNTIF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)

```
=if(countif(range,"TEST"),,"TEST")
```